# Looking for a special rank 2 vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $E\to C$ be a rank $2$, degree $2g-2$, holomorphic vector bundle over a curve of genus $g$.
By Riemann-Roch theorem, 
$$H^0(E)-H^1(E)= \deg(E)+2.(1-g)=0. $$

Question: For which $g$, there is such $E$ with $H^0(E)=0$ (and thus $H^1(E)=0$ as well)?

Comment: This question is equivalent to asking for which curves there exists a rank-2 vector bundle $E$ such that $H^0(E) = 0 = H^1(E)$. It's pretty clear that $\mathscr{O}(1) \oplus \mathscr{O}(1)$ works for the curve $\mathbb P^1$ (i.e., $g=0$), but I have a feeling the OP already knew this and/or doesn't care about this case.

Comment: Dear Mohammed: These are called "Ulrich bundles" in the literature.  There are many references.  

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every curve admits a degree g-1 line bundle with $h^0=h^1=0$ -- in fact a generic degree g-1 line bundle has this property, since the space of degree g-1 divisors is g-1 dimensional, but the space of line bundles is g dimensional.  Taking the direct sum of two such line bundles will give you a bundle of the type you are seeking.

Comment: Is it possible for this line bundle $L$ to satisfy $L\otimes L = K_C$ ($K_C$ is the canonical bundle) as well?

Comment: Yes. A line bundle and an isomorphism $L^{\otimes 2} \cong K_C$ is called a *spin structure* on $C$. The moduli space of pairs ($C$, spin structure on $C$) has two components since one can show that the quantity $h^0(L)\pmod 2$ is constant in families. In the moduli space of "even" spin curves, the ones where $L$ is effective form a divisor. So a general even spin curve gives an example.

Comment: Another name for such $L$ is {\it theta-characteristic}.